# how to get filter input value in Ag grid filter with react?

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

I'm trying to get the value a user types as input of a filter with AG grid,
like in a simple input with onChange function.

i tried onFilterChanged, but couldn't catch the value.

```
<div style={containerStyle}>
          <div style={gridStyle} className="ag-theme-alpine">
            <AgGridReact
              rowData={all.flat().reverse()}
              columnDefs={columnDefs}
              groupIncludeFooter={true}
              groupIncludeTotalFooter={true}
              defaultColDef={defaultColDef}
              animateRows={true}
              onFilterChanged={(e: any) =>
                console.log("filter has changed", e)
              }
            ></AgGridReact>
          </div>
        </div>
```

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`gridRef` is necessary and loop all columns if any of each column contains a filtered string

html

```html
    ref={gridRef}
    onFilterChanged={handleFilter}
```

jsx

```js
const GridExample = () => {
    const gridRef = useRef();
///...columndefs and rowdata
}
this.handleFilter=()=> {
    alert(gridRef.current.api.getFilterInstance('athlete').appliedModel.filter);
  };
```

if second filter is active, `gridRef.current.api.getFilterInstance('athlete').appliedModel.condition1.filter` and `gridRef.current.api.getFilterInstance('athlete').appliedModel.condition2.filter`

[working demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/9xSyvDYl4MIkA87c?open=index.jsx)

**Edited to Add:**
`gridRef.current.api.getFilterModel()` is possible which outputs json objects of all given filters.

```
{
            'athlete':
            {
                   condition1:
                   {
                          filterType: 'text',
                          type: 'contains',
                          filter: 'a'
                   },
                   condition2:
                   {
                          filterType: 'text',
                          type: 'contains',
                          filter: 'b'
                   },
                   filterType: "text",
                   operator: "AND"
            },
            'age':
            {
                   filterType: 'text',
                   type: 'contains',
                   filter: 'c'
            },
}
```

and if it is global filter (filtered from textbox outside grid),
`gridRef.current.api.filterManager.quickFilterParts` is possible

Comment: @tahamaatof Always welcome mate :)

Answer (score 1):

we can use the `params.api.getFilterModel()` to get the filer value of individual column

```
const cellRender = params => {
    const filterInput = params.api.getFilterModel().Name?.filter
    const value = params.value

    if (filterInput && value) {
        return <Name name={String(value)} highlight={String(filterInput)} />
    }
    return value
}


export default [
    {
        cellRenderer: cellRender,
        field: 'name',
        headerName: 'Name',
        headerTooltip: 'Name',
        tooltipField: 'name'
    }
]
```